# Lowest triangle count object remotely resembling a sphere?

Tags: modeling

I want to create an object which will be aptly named 'glob of glue'.

Players are expected to use a plenty of them, so minimizing face count matters - in particular, triangle count, as that's what matters in the game engine; the neat 12 faces of a dodecahedron factually convert to 60 triangles which is no longer that nice.

I tried a hexahedron made of two tetrahedrons, but the edges are too sharp for my liking. After applying 'subdivision surface' I obtained something of 18 faces (acceptable) and quite satisfying 'by appearance' - but all the walls are quadrangles, doubling the triangle count. 36 triangles is over my budget.

[image]

What shape achievable with, say, 20 triangles would (remotely) resemble a sphere / shapeless blob? How to go about creating it in Blender?

(...and I realize probably foregoing a model altogether and using a particle instead would be best for the role, unfortunately the game engine is out of my control).

Comment: probably a standard Icosphere with subdivision 1 (default is 2) is what you're looking for... (20 faces, though: to get lower amount you can play with the decimate modifier)

Comment: @m.ardito: Doesn't look that bad, 20 triangles leans on the limit. Let's wait some to see if someone doesn't have something even better; if not, submit that as an answer.